# Using the power platform for a multi tenant web application

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-dynamics, microsoft-portal

I need to build an application that mostly displays grids of DB information, and drill down edit forms. It has a few "analytics" on it, but nothing fancy. The application must be multi tenant and hold a load of a few thousand concurrent, external users, that authenticate using SSO/JWT.

Is the Microsoft power platform a viable platform for this type of solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Building such kind of applications is the main purpose of [Power Apps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/).

> Build apps in hours—not months—that easily connect to data, use Excel-like expressions to add logic, and run on the web, iOS, and Android devices.